# DDD - How do scheduled tasks fit in CQRS/DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am trying out CQRS, Event Sourcing and DDD in a project and I want to model a **Reminder Service**.

The context is as follows: Person A creates a Task for Person B and sets a Deadline for Person B to complete it (also it can be a recurring Task, so when he completes it the next due date would be for example in 30 days again). The Reminder functionality should remind Person B to complete the task. Also Person B should see in the system his Tasks and their due date.

My Question is where should this Reminder Service 'live' in a CQRS/DDD Architecture? I came up with 2 options:

**Option 1**

The Reminder functionality is its own bounded context and the BC listens to events sent from the Task Creation, (e.g. TaskCreated). It then creates some Kind of ReminderAggregate. A scheduled Task inside the Reminder BC (maybe in Infrastructure Layer?) checks everyday all ReminderAggregates and sends a Notification to the Customer if certain Criteria is met. This would decouple the Task BC from the Reminder BC. When a TaskCompleted Event is emitted, the ReminderAggregate would be deleted. Also in future maybe it would  be possible to have other reminders not connected to tasks but other stuff in the system.

**Option 2**

Keep the reminder functionality inside the Task Aggregate. A scheduled process inside the Tasks BC checks all open Tasks for their due date and sends for example everyday an email, to the assigned Person, when the due date is 10 days away.

Maybe there are better solutions to this, but I am still too new to these concepts to know how to model it properly

Comment: You should consider bringing your problem to the ddd-cqrs-es discord: https://discord.gg/sEZGSHNNbH

Comment: The way Bounded Context is used in this question does not make sense. A BC is a language boundary. You define a separate BC if a word means something different for various people. That’s not the case here. Could you correct your question?